# C# Duration is a type but used like a variable

Tags: c#

I am following the steps of the book 'A brain friendly guide: Head First C#' by O'Reilly Media

And have come across this error `'Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`

When inserting this code `Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)));`

I would like to know why I am getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

Below is the full method of code that has been portrayed in the book if it helps, if it just creates clutter and makes it difficult for users to read the text I shall remove the method.

```
private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            {
                From = from;
                To = to;
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
           };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
            }
```

Comment: `new DoubleAnimation();` A semicolon terminates a statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is trying to tell you that you cannot name a field in an anonymous type with the name of a type `Duration` because your initializer syntax is incorrect: you put a semicolon after `new DoubleAnimation()`, so the rest of the initializer is treated like a stand-alone block of code.

Here is the proper syntax:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation {
    From = from,
    To = to,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
};
```

I removed parentheses after `new DoubleAnimation` because the call is made to the default constructor. I also replaced semicolons with commas to comply with C# syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As Jesse pointed out, you should remove the semicolons and replace them with commas:

```
private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
            };
                Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
                storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
                storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
                storyboard.Begin();
            }
```